# Collapsible panes (div) on right and left side of adjustable main content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to have two collapsible panes on both sides of my page, but at the same time the main content should adjust its width based on the status of the panes.

here is a start [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zFANM/23/) with the left pane working fine, but it does not seem the same with the right pane.

```
<div id="index-container">
    <div id="left-side-bar">left side bar</div>
    <div id="index-main-content">main content</div>
    <div id="right-side-bar">right side bar</div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is Your [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zFANM/25/)

```
#right-side-bar{
width: 20%;
float:right;
background-color:#9C6;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nop.. try adding height to #index-main-content and the right side bar goes down... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zFANM/26/)